# How to use the filename in the header as default filename for FileReference.download?

Tags: apache-flex, air

in our AIR application, I want to user to be able to download a file to a location of his choice. This can be easily done with:

```
var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileReference.download( request );
```

The `URLRequest` points to a servlet `http://myserver/myapp/download`. If I do a `navigateToUrl` in our web application, the browser will properly use the filename put in the HTTP header by the server. However, in the AIR application, it will propose `download` as the file name for the user (because this is the last part of the URL probably).

How can I make sure the download in the AIR application will also use that name?

I am aware that the `download` method has an optional 2nd parameter to set the default file name, but I don't know what is in the HTTP header as file name at compile time of the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with the following code:

```
    var stream:URLStream = new URLStream();
    stream.addEventListener( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, function ( event:HTTPStatusEvent ):void
    {
        var fileName:String;
        for each(var requestHeader:URLRequestHeader in event.responseHeaders)
        {
            if (requestHeader.name == "Content-Disposition")
            {
                fileName = requestHeader.value.substring( requestHeader.value.indexOf( "=" ) + 2, requestHeader.value.length - 1 );
                logger.info( "Found filename in HTTP headers: {0}", [fileName] );
                break;
            }
        }

        stream.close();

        logger.info("Start file download...");
        var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
        fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, download_completeHandler );
        fileReference.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, download_progressHandler );
        fileReference.download( request, fileName );
    } );

    stream.load( request );
```

I first use the `URLStream` class to get the HTTP headers. As soon as I have the headers, I close the stream (since it is a big file, I don't want to download the actual data just yet). From the headers, I extract the filename that is in the `Content-Disposition` part and use that name as the default name to pass into `FileReference.download()` method.